# Node.js Bug Or Am I Doing it Wrong? ES Modules

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

I am using <s>the latest</s> Node version 16.16.0, and in my project's `package.json` I have:

```
"type": "module",
```

That *should* enable ES Module (ie. `import`) syntax.  However, when I try to run any file:

```
node some/path/file.js
```

I get:

```
> (node:1358624) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> /home/me/project/some/path/file.js:1
> import { test } from 'ava';
> ^^^^^^
> 
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
>     at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
>     at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
>     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
>     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
>     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
>     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

In other words, Node seems to be ignoring my package.json and treating the project like a CommonJS one ... even though I have:

```
"type": "module",
```

Is this a bug in Node, or is there any way I could somehow be accidentally telling Node "switch back to CommonJS"?  I would very much prefer *not* to have to rename every one of my files to `.mjs`.

**EDIT:**  For those asking about my `package.json` file.  It (obviously) has a bunch of stuff in it, but even if I reduce it to *just:

```
{
  "type": "module",
}
```

I *still* have the issue.

**EDIT #2:**  I don't understand the votes to close.  There's a clear question here:

> Is this a bug in Node, or is there any way I could somehow be accidentally telling Node "switch back to CommonJS"?

And all of the information necessary to answer it is provided.  You don't need *any* specific `package.json`, you simply need to know that sub-directory `package.json` files trump parent-directory ones (and thus that one could "tell node to switch back" by having a sub-directory file).

Comment: Please show your whole `package.json` file.  And, is that file in the exact same directory as the `file.js` you are trying to run?  This is not a bug in nodejs (running ESM modules works just fine).  It's a configuration error on your part in some way and we have to figure out what that configuration error is.

Comment: FYI 16.16.0 _isn't_ the latest Node version (currently 18.7.0) or even the latest Node 16/LTS version (currently 16.17.0)

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Just to be clear here, whether it's 16.16.0 or 16.17.0 or 18.7 won't likely make any difference in this question.

Comment: @jfriend00 indeed not, in any of the three the error I actually get is `The requested module 'ava' does not provide an export named 'test'`

Comment: Are you sure that node actually finds your *package.json* file?

Comment: Why did you post and disappear?  With the amount of rep you have, surely you should know that everything works better here if you don't just disappear for long periods of time.  People are trying to help and you're just not around to engage.  Not much we can do when that happens.  Either your package.json is wrong or it's not in the right place or you have some other unknown environment things that is messing things up.  A properly configured project will run ESM modules just fine without having to rename to .mjs.

Comment: I posted five hours ago, that's not very long.

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure!  In fact, I just tested now, and even if I make my `package.json` just "`{`" (ie. clearly invalid) I still get the exact same error (*not* anything about my `package.json` being invalid).  To be clear, the `package.json` *is* in my project folder (let's call it `foo`).  The file is in a sub-folder, and I'm running the command from the main project folder, so I'm not sure why/how Node could ignore my `package.json`.

Comment: If it's not complaining about a clearly invalid package.json file, then it's definitely not finding it and that is the problem.  The #1 place to put It should be in the same folder as the main JS file you're running from the command line.

Comment: FYI, your question still doesn't contain enough info for anyone to answer.  You haven't added either the package.json file or the directory structure of where it's located to your question relative to the file you are starting your project with.  Either the file is defective or nodejs isn't finding it.

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer.  Thanks for everyone's feedback in helping me figure it out, especially Bergi: his comment made me realize that maybe the `package.json` I was looking at wasn't being respected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue wound up being something really stupid ...

**I had (another) `package.json` file in the file's subdirectory!**

Originally I had asked:

> is there any way I could somehow be accidentally telling Node "switch back to CommonJS"?

It turned out, there was! The `package.json` that was in the directory *closer to the file being run* took precedence over the project's `package.json`.